# How to display charts dynamically other than by using MSCharts?

Tags: 2010, 2013, development, asp.net, chart

I would like to display a pie chart in a custom SharePoint application page. One option to do this is by using MSCharts and `<asp:Chart>` tag. However, getting this to work requires modification of **web.config**. Because I would like my app to be easily deployable to different environments (across farms and web applications), I'd prefer not having to edit web.config to get charts to work, as this requires tedious extra work to avoid potential production problems (as far as I know - is there an easy automatic way to solve this?).

Are there any other (ideally out of the box) charting options that I can use in a robust, easy-to-deploy way, i.e. I'd like to minimize the chance of production environment problems due to e.g. invalid web.config?

Ideally, I'd like to avoid scripts and would have total C# control over the displayed data.

Comment: I ansered a similar question yesterday (suggesting client side script): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53224/sharepoint-2013-office-365-how-do-i-chart-a-list/94462#94462

Comment: Are you able to use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)?

Answer (score 1):

A possible scenario, if you need to modify the data source programmatically, would be to create a custom Web Part that inherits from the Chart Web Part.
Then you can set the values using the properties from the base class by overriding the binding methods.

I would highly recommend first adding a Chart Web Part using the SP User Interface, configuring it and then exporting it so that you can peek into the correct syntax for the properties you want to set.

One of the key methods would be CreateDataBinding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.webcontrols.chartwebpart.createdatabinding(v=office.14).aspx

And one of the key properties to look at would be ChartXml.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.webcontrols.chartwebpart_properties(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the out of the box chart web part?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-the-chart-web-part-HA101889216.aspx

Comment: I've encountered this one, but haven't found anything on how to work with it dynamically - e.g. insert it in aspx, bind custom data etc.