# How to get summary report in sharepoint custom list form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, html

IS there any way to get summary of all responses from Custom list form. I have created the custom list form and received all the responses from people. Now I want to get the summary (like Graphical summary).

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 you can try Out of the Box Gantt view for a list. Please see the description below:

**Gantt View

```
View list items in a Gantt chart to see a graphical representation of how a team's tasks relate over time**
```

Comment: Where is it. i didnt find it anywhere in sharepoint 2013

Comment: Create view and you will find the type of views to be created

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Chart web part` to show data summary from List as Graphical summary :

**For SharePoint 2010**

- Begin by either creating a page or by opening an existing page for editing.
- On the ribbon, click the Insert tab, and then in the Web Parts group, click Web Parts.
- In the Categories section, click Business Data.
- In the Web Parts section, click Chart Web Part, and then click Add.
- Locate the Chart Web Part that you want to edit, and then click the Data & Appearance hypertext.
- In the Connect to Data Source page, select the data source that you want to use, and then click Next.
- In the Retrieve and Filter Data page, preview the data that will be used for the Chart Web Part.
- In the Data Connection & Chart Appearance Wizards page, click Connect Chart to Data to open the Data Connection Wizard.
- In the Choose a Data Source page, select a data source type, and then click Next.
- After you have finished previewing and filtering the data, click Next.
- To optionally specify how you want the data to be displayed, use the Bind Chart to Data page.
- Do this by specifying one column for the Y Field, and another column for the X Field.
- Click Finish to view the chart in its page.

For more details check [Create a chart by using the Chart Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-chart-by-using-the-Chart-Web-Part-d781ed6d-cbdd-4da9-a5bf-cf346c98db72)

**For SharePoint online**

This [tool](http://www.aasoftech.com/SitePages/How%20to%20create%20a%20Chart%20from%20SharePoint%20List.aspx) allows you to create Google chart using client object model. See also similar thread [SharePoint 2013 (Office 365) - How do I chart a list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53224/sharepoint-2013-office-365-how-do-i-chart-a-list)

**For SharePoint 2013**

Try this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b011e137-70eb-4092-b8e2-e5ed9a5ead7e/sharepoint-2013-how-do-i-chart-a-list?forum=sharepointgeneral) to can use Chart web part at SharePoint 2013

Comment: Am not getting that Chart web part option in my sahrepoint 2013

Comment: it has been removed in SharePoint 2013 ,  I read the previous answer and I think you are working with 2010 , no problem there's a method to export it to 2013, Please check the updated answer.

Comment: It say's export webpart from 2010 sharepoint. i do not have 2010 version in my system. Please help me with any alternative option

Comment: can you work with google chart via  CSOM ?

Comment: Am not aware of this function. Is there any way to add "Chart web part" only in sharepoint 2013

Comment: let me try to export one from SP 2010 and send it to you